# Problems linking my driver

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, driver, wdk

I've got quite some programming experience, but I'm new to windows driver development. I am currently trying to create a simple display driver, following [this turorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12878/Driver-Development-Part-Introduction-to-Display).
The goal is to simulate a second (and in the future: third, etc.) display, which is purely virtual and just renders to a framebuffer. I could then grab the contents of the virtual screen via VNC and render it to a remote machine.

The Problem is: If I try to build the project (using VisualStudio 2013 and WDK 8.1), I get a LNK2019 error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "DriverEntry" in function "GsDriverEntry".    E:\VS_Projects\MViz\MVizVMonGDIDrv\BufferOverflowFastFailK.lib(gs_driverentry.obj)  MVizVMonGDIDrv
```

There is no `DriverEntry` function in my code, just a `BOOL DrvEnableDriver`, acting as the equivalent for `DriverEntry` in a display driver.

Any ideas on how to resolve that error?

Comment: seems to be an issue with the library `BufferOverflowFastFailK.lib`.

Comment: It only contains a DriverEntry function in the miniport driver, which is working fine. The compilation of the GDI driver is what is failing.

If I include `BufferOverflowK.lib` it fails over that lib, instead of `BufferOverflowFastFailK.lib`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution myself: The entry point was wrong. Changing that to `DrvEnableDriver` fixed it.